# Exercise 3.15 from Introduction to Manifolds by Tu

Tags: smooth-manifolds, exterior-algebra

I am wondering about exercise 3.15 on page 25.

If $f$ is a 3-linear function on a vector space $V$ and $v_1,v_2,v_3 \in V$, what is $(Af)(v_1,v_2,v_3)$?

I have by far that
$$
(Af)(v_1,v_2,v_3) = -f(v_2,v_1,v_3)-f(v_1,v_3,v_2)-f(v_3,v_2,v_1)+f(v_2,v_3,v_1)+f(v_3,v_1,v_2)+f(v_1,v_2,v_3). 
$$
Is this correct?

$Af$ is defined to be $(Af)(v_1,...,v_k) = \sum_{\sigma \in S_k}f(v_{\sigma(1)},...,v_{\sigma(k)})$, or in short, $Af = \sum(sgn\sigma)\sigma f$.

$\sigma$ represents all the permutations.

I also don't get the significance of those operators introduced in the book, can someone help me with the importance of those operators?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Try to use the formula editor, then your text will look more accurate and clear.

Comment: What does $A$ represent? How is $Af$ defined? Is that formula you gave the definition of $Af$, and if so then what exactly are you asking? Your post doesn't make much sense without this kind of information.

Comment: $A$ is the alternating operator. Symmetric and and antisymmetric $k$-linear maps (tensors) play a very important role in differential geometry, so having operators that 'symmetrize' and 'alternate' is quite useful.

Comment: I have to say that I too don't understand the point of the exercise, particularly as it's starred. I get the same answer as you do.